# Telegram bot to autoreply to a gif sent to it by the user

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

I want to create an autoreply bot on Telegram with the specific condition:

1. message send to it is a .gif
2. the message is forwarded from another chat

Essentially I want something like `content_type=['gif']` just that GIF is not in the list of content types.

I am using python and `aiogram`.

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types

@dp.message_handler(content_types=\['video','audio','photo','document','voice'\], is_forwarded = True, user_id = userlist)
async def check(message):
      await message.reply("Did you share or forward this with others? \\n \\n Please select your response.",    reply_markup=keyboard_inline2)
```

Comment: Maybe this info can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 0):

You can read the aiogram docs here: https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/dev-3.x/api/types/animation.html#aiogram.types.animation.Animation

You can use content type animation

> This object represents an animation file (GIF or H.264/MPEG-4 AVC
> video without sound).

```
@dp.message_handler(content_types=['animation'], is_forwarded = True, user_id = userlist)
async def check(message):
      await message.reply("Did you share or forward this with others? \\n \\n Please select your response.",    reply_markup=keyboard_inline2)
```